# garchFit() in R returning the same number in all fitted values

Tags: r, statistics

I have tried to use garchFit in R and found out something very strange, it seems that all the fitted are the same. I tried to use the example in the R page and found the same results.

If you open R and type the following:

```
library(fGarch);
## UNIVARIATE TIME SERIES INPUT:
# In the univariate case the lhs formula has not to be specified ...
# A numeric Vector from default GARCH(1,1) - fix the seed:
N = 200
x.vec = as.vector(garchSim(garchSpec(rseed = 1985), n = N)[,1])
garchFit(~ garch(1,1), data = x.vec, trace = FALSE)
# An univariate timeSeries object with dummy dates:
x.timeSeries = dummyDailySeries(matrix(x.vec), units = "GARCH11")
gfit = garchFit(~ garch(1,1), data = x.timeSeries, trace = FALSE)
```

Then doing the following sanity check seems to indicate that the residuals were computed correctly:

```
gfit@residuals == (x.vec - gfit@fitted)
```

however if you examine the contents of gfit@fitted, you can see that all the values are the same ! So basically the garchFit function found a horizontal line ?

Is that expected from this example ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GARCH models the variance of the series and hence we wouldn't expect the fitted values (estimates of the mean of the series) to change because all you did was specify a model for the variance.

It is implied that there is an ARMA(0,0) for the mean in the model you fitted:

```
R> gfit = garchFit(~ garch(1,1), data = x.timeSeries, trace = TRUE)

Series Initialization:
 ARMA Model:                arma
 Formula Mean:              ~ arma(0, 0)
 GARCH Model:               garch
 Formula Variance:          ~ garch(1, 1)
```

If you fit the series with a model for the mean as well as the variance then the fitted value **do** vary:

```
R> gfit2 = garchFit(~ arma(1,1) + garch(1,1), data = x.timeSeries, trace = FALSE)
R> head(gfit2@fitted)
   1970-01-01    1970-01-02    1970-01-03    1970-01-04    1970-01-05 
-0.0010093158 -0.0004840687 -0.0002678956 -0.0006093776 -0.0003781936 
   1970-01-06 
 0.0004521798
```

Comment: It all makes sense, but what I wanted is to model the volatility itself. Is there any easy way to get the fitted series on the quadratic variation (the volatility) ?

Comment: Does `gfit2@h.t` give you what you want. See its description in `?garchFit`, which I presume you have read?

Comment: I read it but before to understand what S4 classes were so I did not understood it at that time. Thank you Gavin !